# Как правильно организовать передачу данных в Netty?

Tags: java, netty

У меня есть абстрактный класс `MainSocket`. Его для удобства реализует `SocketClient`. В `MainSocket` есть метод отправки данных и создание соединения.  Когда я пытаюсь отправить сообщение, у меня вылетает `NullPointerException`.

Главный класс:

```
public abstract class MainSocket {
    private final static String HOST = "localhost";
    private static final int PORT = 8790;

    /*представляет собой многопоточный цикл событий ,
    который обрабатывает операции ввода / вывода.*/
    private EventLoopGroup workerGroup ;
    private Channel channel;
    private ChannelFuture future;
    private Bootstrap bootstrap;

    /*Публичные методы для наследников*/
    public void sendData(ByteBuf out) {
        outData(out);
    }

    public void connect() {
        openConnection();
    }

    /*TODO Абстрактыне методы для наследников*/
    public abstract void sendMessage(String msg);
    public abstract void createConnect();

    /*TODO Главный метод отправки пакетов*/
    private void outData(ByteBuf out) {
        future = channel.writeAndFlush(out);
        //future.channel();
    }

    /*TODO Устанавливает соединение*/
    private void openConnection () {
        workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();                      
        try {
            bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
            bootstrap.group(workerGroup).channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new SocketInit());
            future = bootstrap.connect(HOST,PORT).sync();
            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс-наследник преобразует `String` в `ByteByf`:

```
public class SocketClient extends MainSocket {
    private MainSocket clientSocket;
    ClientEncoder clientEncoder;

    @Override
    public void createConnect() {
        connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        final String msga = msg;
        ByteBuf data = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(msga.getBytes());
        sendData(data);
    }
}
```